# view entry number method that takes user inputed integer and matches that integer with array index to show an entry of address book

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, user-input

My apologies if this is a duplicate but I couldn't find an answer that provides a solution to my problem. I'm trying to make a method for an address book that takes user input (integer) and matches that integer with the index of an array of entries then prints the entry to the user. Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

```
def view_entry_number
    print "Enter entry number: "
    selection = gets.to_i
    case selection
    when selection == (1...100) 
      system "clear"
      puts entry.to_s
    else
      system "clear"
      puts "#{selection} is not a valid input"
    end
  end
```

Comment: I think the question would be more clearer if you give an example like a given array, given input and expected output.

Comment: Good point. I'll make sure to include that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
  def view_entry_number
    ary = ['one','two','three']
    print "Enter entry number: "
    selection = gets.to_i
    if (1..ary.length).include?(selection)
      puts ary[selection - 1]
    else
      puts "#{selection} is not a valid input"
    end
  end
```

Which returns:

```
  2.3.1 :281 > view_entry_number
  Enter entry number: 1
  one
   => nil 

  2.3.1 :282 > view_entry_number
  Enter entry number: 2
  two
   => nil 

  2.3.1 :283 > view_entry_number
  Enter entry number: 3
  three
   => nil 

  2.3.1 :284 > view_entry_number
  Enter entry number: 4
  4 is not a valid input
   => nil 

  2.3.1 :285 > view_entry_number
  Enter entry number: 0
  0 is not a valid input
   => nil 

  2.3.1 :286 > view_entry_number
  Enter entry number: f
  0 is not a valid input
   => nil
```